# "look at what" vs "look what"

Tags: grammar, phrases

Which is correct "Look at what I found." or "Look what I found."
The former has always bothered me, but I'm not sure what the grammar rules would say.

Comment: Grammaticality is determined by usage. To that end, you might be interested in this ngram, which shows that the version without *at* is more frequent. One can't call it the "correct" version, however: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look++what+I+found%2C+look+at+what+I+found&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20what%20I%20found%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20at%20what%20I%20found%3B%2Cc0

Comment: An even more compelling n-gram, if you change the predicate to "what you've done" the version with *at* does not occur at all: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+what+you%27ve+done%2C+look+at+what+you%27ve+done&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20what%20you%20%27ve%20done%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Wow! I love ngrams. Thanks for turning me on to it!

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiomatic usage of "look" which is  generally used without the preposition "at" when you are telling someone to be careful and it is followed by "when, where, what and who:"

***[Look](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look) :***

> - [ I ] used when you are telling someone to be careful or to pay attention:
>
>   - [ + question word ] ***Look where you're going!***
>   - ***Look at the time - we're late!***

Cambridge   Dictionary

***[Look what you have done](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/look-what-you-ve-done)***:

> - used when you are annoyed with someone and want them to look at the result of their action
>
>   - ***Look what*** you’ve done! The chair’s ruined now.

MacMillan Dictionary

Comment: But *Look (at) what I found* is rarely used by native speakers "when [we]  are telling someone to be careful" or "when [we] are annoyed with someone," which are what  the sources you have copy and pasted here refer to.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - I suggest you read my answer again, and you should support what you say with reliable references.

Comment: @JOSH if you're going to pick nits, you should properly spell and capitalize Cambridge.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, "look at what I found" is asking to look "at" something the first person has found.
"look what I found" is asking just to have attention.